# Calculate total bit rate

Tags: homework, video-processing

I want to calculate the total bit rate of a video system.

In order to calculate the total bit rate for a 1080/50p video system(4:2:2) we need:

```
•   Luminance sampling rate:Fs=13.5MHz  (standard for 4:2:2)
•   Number of bits: N=8
•   Number of components per PEL:  M=3 (Y,Cb,Cr)
•   Number of lines: L=1080 
•   Line duration: Tline=?
•   Frame Rate:  Fr=50
```

I dont know how to find line duration. Is line duration Tline=L/Fs ??

Comment: If each frame scans all the $1080$ lines of the image, and there are $50$ frames in a second, what is the duration of the scan of one line? What if the scanning was interleaved so that each line got scanned once every two frames? What if the scan is _progressive_ as that `p` in `1080/50p` seems to indicate?

Comment: It is 1/(50*1080) with progressive scan = 1.85*10^-5. Am i correct?

Comment: Sounds right but note that $1.85$ etc is an _approximation_ that I would prefer to express in microseconds as $\approx 1.85 \mu$s rather than as $= 1.85\times 10^{-5}$ s.